# Python data not transferring outside of for loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm new to this, please forgive my stupidity as I try to learn Python. Last time I wrote code was in FORTRAN, so I'm a clunky rusty geezer here, trying to clear out some cobwebs.

Everything in the code works correctly up until this part where I want to prune data.

The data array is `u_new` (I'm using a sample array with 10 entries.) I copied it to a second array `sort_array` so I can find the n highest value (in this case n=5) then set everything below that value to zero.

It looks like it works as when I print the values within the loop, it gives the expected, pruned values. But when I print it from outside the loop, the values haven't changed.

What do I need to do to make the `u_new` values change? What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

This is the code for this section:

```
for i in range(0, L):
  if (u_new[i] < prune_value):
     u_new[i] = 0
     print(u_new[i])   

print("u new - pruned", u_new)
```

This is the output:

```
u_new: [0.53 1.41 2.12 2.52 2.84 3.49 0.82 0.   0.   0.  ]
prune value: 1.4138842208188476
0.0
1.4138842208188476
2.116711725483044
2.523693903749505
2.841964339429383
3.4875660392104955
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
u new - pruned [0.53 1.41 2.12 2.52 2.84 3.49 0.82 0.   0.   0.  ]
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. There are some gaps in your code that make this impossible to troubleshoot: `u_new`, `L`, and `prune_value` are not defined. Also you might have a typo in your indentation, cause if `u_new[i] = 0`, `print(u_new[i])` should be `0.0`.

Comment: I tried `u_new = np.fromstring('0.53 1.41 2.12 2.52 2.84 3.49 0.82 0.   0.   0.', sep=' '); L = len(u_new); prune_value = 0.54`, but wasn't able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use np.fromstring and see if that helps. I had spent 15 hours straight working on it, may have been my problem.

Comment: EDIT: I just played with it again. It's working. I wish I could say what I did to make it work, but I have no idea.  I separated this part and started testing, it worked, so I put it back in the whole - and it worked. I'm still as dumb as I was last night.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The difference in precision values of input and output in your given example is suggesting that the issue may be with the way you are getting the input array. Please specify how you are taking input. I tried to run the code, and it is working perfectly fine for me.

```
u_new = [0.53, 1.41, 2.12, 2.52, 2.84, 3.49, 0.82, 0., 0., 0.]
prune_value = 1.4138842208188476
for i in range(0, len(u_new)):
  if (u_new[i] < prune_value):
     u_new[i] = 0

print("u new - pruned", u_new)
```

This gives the expected output:

```
u new - pruned [0, 0, 2.12, 2.52, 2.84, 3.49, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you. I had spent about 15 hours on this yesterday and was crosseyed trying to figure out it.

I'll mess around with the input array. Right now it's a list of 10 numbers to test the code with being input as: u = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3 etc])

Comment: EDIT: I just played with it again. It's working. I wish I could say what I did to make it work, but I have no idea.  I separated this part and started testing, it worked, so I put it back in the whole - and it worked. I'm still as dumb as I was last night.  Thanks for your help!